# Spark submit cluster mode from s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have Spark stand-alone set up on EC2 instances. I'm try to use cluster mode to submit a Spark apllication. The jar is in S3, and access to it is set up via IAM roles. I can run aws s3 cp s3://bucket/dir/foo.jar . to get the jar file - that works fine. However, when I run the following:

```
spark-submit --master spark://master-ip:7077 --class Foo 
--deploy-mode cluster --verbose s3://bucket/dir/foo/jar
```

I get the error outlined below. Seeing that the boxes have IAM roles configured to allow access, what would be the correct way to submit the job? The job itself doesn't use S3 at all...the issue seems to be fetching the jar from S3.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
16/07/04 11:44:09 ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.initialize(S3FileSystem.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1686)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:598)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$DriverRunner$$downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:79)
```

Comment: I'm not sure Spark knows how to work with IAM roles. I think we've tried it over here as well and it failed. Also, when submitting spark jobs in cluster mode, the port is usually defaulted to 6066 if I recall correctly, you can view it in the Spark UI on the top left.

Comment: What did you do in the end? I tried downloading the jar. Client mode works, but cluster mode doesn't seem to copy the jar to the nodes.

Comment: Client mode works because Spark sets a Jetty HTTP server that distributes the jars to the workers, where's in cluster mode they'll need to access S3. We're currently running our streaming job in client mode.

Comment: yeah...that's what I did in the past...was hoping to have cluster mode for the --supervise capability.

Comment: Are you running a streaming job or a batch job?

Comment: This one's batch, but some are streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. I put the jar in a static http server, and use http://server/foo.jar in spark-submit. That seems to work.

Comment: You can always provide the access key and secret key in the S3 url :)

Comment: That's a problem, as I don't *have* an access and secret key...the boxes get access with IAM roles. :)

Comment: There must be a better way to work with AWS. I'm currently testing the resiliency with cluster mode and the `--supervise` flag. Doesn't really work if the worker machine which runs the driver terminates. When I get that sorted, I'll try working with S3 to get the IAM role working.

Comment: Hmm...I think it's for application level crashes.

Comment: The application does get rescheduled on a different worker, but for some reason the previous worker which terminateds IP is passed to the new driver.

Comment: Worth submitting to the spark issue tracker then?

Comment: Definitely. I just cloned the project, I want to open an issue with a possible solution, or at least get close to the problematic area in the code.